# using TCSpinEdit (drop down) in Borland C++

Tags: drop-down-menu, borland-c++

I want to use a "drop-down" functionality in Borland, and I found the  TCSpinEdit component under samples. The problem is that I could only insert integers as values, but I need the user to choose between strings.
Does anyone know how to do that? maybe use another component?

Thanks!

Comment: I use `TComboBox` for that ... easy and stable to use (`TCSpinEdid` had some errors causing App to crash time to time  at least at the time I tried it) Items of combo box are in form of string list so you have native support  for what you need. I usually add mouse wheel navigation on it so you can easily step through items, but the event must be in the owner component. If you still need the up/down buttons then add them ...

Comment: Thanks! it's the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The TComboBox is a great solution.